# HTTP connection fails due to ${}

Tags: c#

My application started giving following error when trying to execute HTTP post request. It started from 13th Jan.

Error:
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

It works, when I removed ${} in my payload. Could anyone pls help?

POST payload:

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "canBePermanentlyDeleted": false,
            "disposition": "wormhole",
            "eTag": "xxxx",
            "id": 10025,
            "isDefault": false,
            "isVisible": true,
            "href": "http://xx.xx.xx.xx.com/(NEXT(${dotNextSession}))/default/Launch.ed?qstoken=${dotNextAuthToken}&eclg_courseId=${courseId}&path=/index.html&json={%22handler_urn%22:%22xx/xx_xl/slink/x-xx-xx_xl%22,%22targetId%22:%22multimedia%22,%22pagelink%22:%22frame%22}",
            "lastModified": "Tue, 08 Feb 2022 05:00:09 GMT",
            "level": 0,
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "http://xx.xx.net/users/xx/courses/xx/menus/xx/items/xx"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "http://xx.xx.net/rels/menus/xx-menu",
                    "href": "http://xx.xx.net/users/xx/courses/xx/menus/xx"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Multimedia Library 1",
            "subMenuId": 0,
            "isUpdating": false,
            "draggable": true,
            "updateInProgress": true,
            "isHidden": false,
            "expanded": true,
            "hasChildren": false,
            "hasChildrenExpanded": false,
            "isMyContent": false,
            "isCourseTool": true,
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's not a client-side error. Did the server crash? `http://xx.xx.xx.xx.com/(NEXT(${dotNextSession}))` isn't a valid URL. Is the server meant to execute `(NEXT(${dotNextSession}))` and use the result in the URL? Perhaps the server couldn't handle this? Or doesn't allow such data in the first place and terminated the connection instead of returning an error?

Comment: In any case, it's impossible to help with the information in this question.

Comment: For the receiver, payload is just a text and it doesn't do anything with that other than sending it to another website.

Comment: And that receiver terminated the connection without even a 500 error. Again, did the server crash? Or did it reject what looked like a script injection attempt?

Comment: Since this came suddenly without any change in applications could this be any security update?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can this be a client side network level error?

Comment: If it was, removing `${dotNextSession}` wouldn't change anything. Did you check the server's logs? The *server* terminated the connection. Did you check what happened there?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The request is not coming to server application when the payload contains ${dotNextSession}. It should fail before coming to server application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.